# Must a class adhere to the documented contract of an interface to be said to implement that interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

I know what implementing an interface means (technically), but I'm not sure if I understand what the "contract" encompasses:

Lets say I make a class `MyList` which implements `java.util.List` (that is, I implement all methods with code that compiles), is `MyList` a `List` then?  OR do I need to read all the comments of the methods I override and make sure my implementation fulfils these "expectation" on the behaviour?

Comment: Is MyList a List? Yes

Comment: @Enzokie So i gould implement `add` to do nothing and `get` to always return null, you would still call it a List?

Comment: As long as you implement the List it is still called a list. At the end of the day it is your decision whether you put something on those implemented methods or throw some Unsupported exception, the fact still remain that it is still called a list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, yes, `MyList` is a `List` if it implements all the methods of the `List` interface. But the compiler is no magician. It can't check that your methods do what they should do. And of course, every method should do what its documentation says it does.

If I receive a `List`, and this `List` is an instance of `MyList`, and I call `list.add("foo")`, I expect "foo" to be added at the end of the list. Not to be removed, or added twice, or whatever other behavior. So, of course, if your class implements `List`, its methods should comply with the contract defined in its API documentation.

Imagine you sell cars. I go to your shop, and buy a car. To me, it's a car because it looks like all the other cars: it has wheels, pedals, windows, etc. But if I press the accelerator, it brakes, and when I turn lights on, it honks, and when I open the windows, it accelerates and kills a poor kid on the road, I won't be happy at all and you'll be in trouble because the car you sold me isn't behaving correctly.

Comment: Haha great example +1

Comment: So then there is no formal way to tell whether my implementation is "right" or "wrong", it sounds pretty vague, it all about (informal) expectations. It would be nice if interface/abstract class comes with an unit-test which decides whether the implementing class fulfils all expectations. Currently, the API documentation could change, making my implementation suddenly invalid (without my knowledge).

Comment: The JDK doesn't provide such a unit test. It's up to you to implement it. But the contract will never change: that would break all the existing Java code out there. Implementing a standard collection is not a common task at all. The JDK, and common libraries such as Guava, provide all you need for 99.999% of the use-cases. I can't remamber having implemented a standard collection once in my 20 years of Java programming.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth One simple way to do that is as does Python: you can include examples of usage in the documentation and you can run them as tests. However this is actually pretty fragile. The "real way" of doing this would be going towards formal methods and provide *proofs* to the compiler that the methods satisfy the properties required by the interface. There exists languages that do this.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the difference between a class and an interface is that a class has method implementations.  An interface does not.  So an interface may have an add() method, but wouldn't say anything about how add works.  A class would need to define how add works.

You implement an interface the moment you put `implements InterfaceName` in your class definition.  You must then define all the methods of the interface, or your app won't compile.  Then yes, it would be correct to say MyClass is a MyInterface-  you could even go MyInterface interface = new MyClass();

And yes, you should read all the comments and make sure your class implements the interface in the expected way.  Otherwise you'll end up with something that compiles but may not work right.

Comment: Fixed that before you even posted this :)

Comment: Uh..java 8+ allows implementation on the interface. Limited, but is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is a necessary minimum for the contract: as you say, if it doesn't compile, you can't have fulfilled the contract! But the language may not be able to define and restrict the full requirements of the interface, so you should heed those expectations too.

One easy example is the `ICloneable` interface. If all you do is implement

```
public MyObject clone() {
    return (MyObject)super.clone();
} // clone()
```

then you've fulfilled the language contract, and perhaps your class' contract too. But if your class contains a `List`, then you'll surprise your users: "That didn't `clone()` right!"

The contract also includes user expectations. Break them, and although a language lawyer may say your class is-a `List`, others won't agree..

Comment: What is the `ICloneable`-interface you are talking about? [java.lang.Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) is a marker-interface and does not even force you to override `clone()`. But you are right, marker interfaces ([Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) would be another popular example) exist only as a kind of promise to fulfill the contract - it is trivial to make an implementation compile, but without also fulfilling the contract, it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

> is MyList a List?

In order to answer this question you need first to understand what interfaces do or what are they written for...

Dont forget interfaces can offer you a very important detachment between what a class **can** do and **how** they do it...
so technically implementing an interface is not about asking if an object **IS something** but more about asking **how** an object can do something

so when you say List myContainer = new ArrayList();
you are defining an object that can do all the things a list can do...
add, remove, get etc etc

you can say it it a list, I would say it can do what a list can do..